# Table loop printing backwords & in reverse [Django Template]

Tags: python, django, templates

```
<table>
    <tr>
    {% for i in "5555" %}
    <th> {{ forloop.revcounter }} </th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
    {% for i in "11" %}
    <th> {{ forloop.revcounter  }} </th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
    {% for i in "1444" %}
    <th> {{ forloop.revcounter  }} </th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>


{% endblock %
```

output:
[I had to use forloop.revcounter so the numbers appeared in order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEWH4.png)

Anyway what I'm trying to do is dynamically generate a stem-and-leaf-plot sort of graph, but encountered this weird issue I am not sure how to solve.

CSS (there is more, but this is the relevant bit, I don't think CSS impacts this? as I am using a template with other CSS defined)

```
table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: are you trying iterate in reverse order?

Comment: It will be easier if you show the desired output, and the output you get using `forloop.counter`

Comment: @at14 No I'm just trying to print the table out normally, but as you can see from the picture there's two empty blocks in the middle row, which should appear at the end of the row not at the beginning. If you use forloop.counter the numbers are reversed (I don't want them reversed) and come up as 4 3 2 1 etc.

Comment: @schwobaseggl The output of forloop.counter is the opposite of forloop.revcounter, so the cells would have 4 3 2 1 instead of 1 2 3 4 etc

I want the tables to print from left to right, so in the middlw row, there would be two empty spaces at the end

Comment: I think you must be missing out a detail that explains the output you are getting. Ignoring the Django template language, if I try the following table in html the columns fill from left to right: `<table><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th></tr><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr>/table>`. Are you using a right-to-left language? Is there any CSS?

Comment: @Alasdair Hi thanks, I added the CSS, not sure what you mean by right-to-left. I am using Django, HTML, CSS, Python, Bootstrap,JScript, in my project,

Comment: Some languages like Arabic and Hebrew are written from right-to-left, unlike  English which is written left-to-right. I was just trying to thing of reasons why you might not see the same results as I do when using English in the UK.

Comment: @Alasdair, well I do not have any browser settings that change the reading order (though I do not think this will impact the rendering, i don't know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
    float: right;
}
```

You have explicitly said you want the elements to float right. This means any spaces will be on the left of the table.

If you remove `float: right;` (or change to `float: left;`) then the spaces will be on the right side of the table. You should switch from `revcounter` to `counter` at the same time.

Comment: this fixed it..thanks! I put float: right without knowing what it properly does (just to clear the float). Sho